# using split and map in jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

```
const arr = ['name', 'contact number']

const App = () => (
  <div style={styles}>
  Add {arr.split(',').map(o=>o)}
  </div>
);
```

why this won't work? I want to print Add name & contact, but stuck at splitting it.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking to join the values

`Add {arr.join(',')}`

Below links should help you

[MDN split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

[MDN join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to split. I think you are trying to join them:

```
const arr = ['name', 'contact number']

const App = () => (
  <div style={styles}>
  Add {arr.join(',')}
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using 2 functions wrong:

1. `split` is supposed to be used to split a *string* into an array, around the provided character. You already have the resulting array.
2. `.map(o=>o)` is useless - it basically returns the same array provided.

You're probably looking to do this `Add {arr.join(' & ')}`.